# Generics what does <?> actually mean?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does List<?> mean in java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics)
>   [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Apologies but it was difficult trying to search for `<?>`.

What does  mean in regards to Java generics? I understand `<A extends B>` and `<A super B>`, but I have never seen this question mark on its own before.

Comment: Try searching with "Symbol hound" - http://www.symbolhound.com/

Comment: **TL;DR version:** You put the `?` thingy in between the `<>` thingies when Java complains about wanting a type.

Comment: @Andrew - godlike explanation

Answer (score 75):

`<?>` is a shorthand for `<? extends Object>`, it's also known as an *unbounded wildcard*. So you can specify any type of object in your generic.

For example the `List` class is declared as `List<?>`, because it can be a list of anything you want.

---

**Resources:**

- [Effective java - Generics.pdf](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf)
- [Java language specification - Type Arguments and Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)
- [oracle.com - Java tutorials, wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: if anything? then why you are using generic? I don't think so it's good answer to make difference. Because `<E extends Object>` will also allow you to specify any type of object.

Comment: I think this is not true. It depends on the type definition  itself. E.g `A<T extends B>`, then `A<?>` means `anything that extends B`. So `<?>` means "anything that extends the defined parameter of the type".

Answer (score 16):

Its a `wildcard` type. It is short for `? extends Object`

If you get it, all you know is its an `Object`. If you try to set, you can't because it could be any sub class of Object.

Comment: What's the difference between `Class<?>` and 'Class'? Why would I ever need to use `Class<?>` instead of `Class`?

Comment: @ycomp a raw type has generic turned off. For example. Map map; map.entrySet() is a plain set, not a `Set<Entry>` whereas use `Map<?, ?>` and you entrySet is a `Set<Entry<?, ?>>`

Comment: Why not just use Object in that case? What is the advantage of using generics?

Comment: @Davor `<Object>` and `<?>` are not the same. The wildcard means the type is unknown. `<Object>` means you can pass an Object or a sub-class.

Comment: A quick question. In the case of `Map<?, ?>`, does the class of the second `?` has to be the same of the first one?

Comment: @hackjutsu No, one `?` is never assumed to be the same as another `?`

Answer (score 5):

The wildcard Generic is "something". It will be handled as something that extends from Object.

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard,
>   represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of
>   situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable;
>   sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice
>   to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument
>   for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or
>   a supertype.

So, for instance, a `List<?>` is a list containing objects from unknown type.

Answer (score 3):

Its a wildcard. Suppose that you have a collection but the type of that collection is not known, thus you denote it by "?". It simply specifies that the type is not known.
For more details refer http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf
I'm sure it will help.

Comment: is this valid?  "ArrayList<?> list = document.getEmbedded(l, ArrayList.class);"
Will I be able to treat "list" as a String array?  (document is bson)