# Why does the IDE cast to the type <?> inside the equals method that he generated for the generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a generic class for training.

```
public class Pair<T> {
    T first;
    T second;
    private Pair(T first, T second){
        this.first=first;
        this.second=second;
    }
    public T getFirst(){
        return first;
    }
    public T getSecond(){
        return second;
    }
}
```

And I made the ide add equals and hash itself.As a result, she wrote this implementation:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pair<?> pair = (Pair<?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(first, pair.first) && Objects.equals(second, pair.second);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(first, second);
    }
```

Since I haven't figured it out much yet, I don't understand this line:

```
Pair<?> pair = (Pair<?>) o;
```

Why `<?>` ? What kind of person will she put there and where will she take it from?
I understand that  `Pair<T> pair = (Pair<T>) o;` wrong, because there will be an erasure of the type , but what does<? >give us? I will be glad to help you figure it out, thank you.

Comment: `Objects.equals(...)` don't care about the object type, it just compares two instances of type `Object`. As such, it doesn't matter what type `first` and `second` is, they're going to be implicitly cast to `Object` anyway, so `Pair<?>` is simply acknowledging that fact, leaving it up to the `equals(...)` methods of the objects to verify matching types.

Answer (score 0):

`Pair<?>` is a syntactic sugar for `Pair<? extends Object>`
it mean that your eaquls method will accept an object or a class extends object.

You can check this subject for more details
[Generics what does <?> actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392380/generics-what-does-actually-mean)

Comment: And if you make a Pair<Sting>, then <?> will it be String or Object?

Comment: @Alpharius: Neither.  It's a `?`, which means that the code _doesn't know._

Comment: @Alpharius, declaring public class Pair<String> {} make no sense it will be always a generic param like T as if you write class Pair<T> {}

Comment: @MaroineMlis it was the substitution of string instead of T that was interesting to me, if I understood you correctly

Comment: If you have 
Pair<String> p1 = new Pair("A","B");
Pair<String> p2 = new Pair("C","D");
and try to call p1.equals(p2)
the equals method at the run time level will not change for this line 
Pair<?> pair = (Pair<?>) o; 
but the 'first' and 'second' attirbutes will be String fields