# List<?> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); Why I can't add this list1.add(1L); list1.add("hello"); to list1 (unbound wildcard)?

Tags: java

I have a list of an ArrayList:

```
public class Ex{
  public static void main(String[] args){

   List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(1L); 

    list.add("hello");

      List<?> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

      list1.add(1L);

      list1.add("hello");
   }
}
```

Why I can't add 1L , and "hello" String to the unbound wildcard ?

Comment: List<Object> should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does List<?> mean in java generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics)

Comment: Thank you, I know that List<Object> work fine, but the question is here Why I can't add this list1.add(1L); list1.add(“hello”); to list1 to the unbound wildcard ?

Comment: Did you mean [differences between invariance, covariance and contravariance](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47)?

Comment: No , but thanks for helping me.

Comment: The question is here Why I can't add this list1.add(1L); list1.add(“hello”); to list1 to the unbound wildcard ?